# Exclude Orders from Sales Order Summary report

Tags: acumatica

I want to exclude the Sales Order completely based on the InventoryItem I select in report parameter for Sales Order Summary report (Screen ID - SO610500). Meaning, if I select a particular InventoryItem in the parameter, the report should not include the entire Sales Order where I have the selected InventoryItem as one of the line item.

I have tried Additional Filter by adding SOLine.InventoryID, Does Not Contain condition but that seems to work when I have only 1 line item for the order which needs to be excluded but if there are more line items then it is not working.

I have also tried adding new additional parameter to exclude the select InventoryID but that also does the same.

Can anyone please suggest any better way to achiev this goal.

Sales Order 1 (Example) - Contains only 1 line item which I want to exclude from report.
[image]
Sales Order 2 (Example) - Contains 2 line items out of which 1 item I want to exclude from the report.
[image]
Sales Order Summary Report - Additional filter condition I have added
[image]
Sales Order Summary Report - The report itself, which do not list the first sales order but has second sales order.
[image]

Comment: Not sure who has downvoted but please provide an explanation as to what I am missing in the question? Please explain.

Comment: Don't worry about it, question looks fine. Some people unfamiliar with Acumatica watch review queues and do that from time to time.

Comment: Thank you @HB_ACUMATICA

Comment: The hard part here is the SQL. If you were able to achieve the filter using a single SQL query without a SQL sub-query then it could be implemented in the report table schema. We had a tutorial on SO documentation showing how to use a Graph with a report which allows you to have view delegates and more complex data manipulation. That approach is more work to setup but is more flexible and will allow the filter easily: http://www.riptutorial.com/acumatica/example/25273/this-article-covers-example-showing-how-to-create-report-using-memory-records-

Comment: Is there a way I can use SubReport, pass the selected report parameter value to SubReport first and then use this SubReport as some source to exclude the Orders in the report which I do not want it.

Comment: I wouldn't think so but I've never used sub-report.

Comment: Unable to figure out SQL without sub-query. Also, even if we can figure out the SQL, not sure how to derive report from different tables from data view.

Comment: The report builder Table schema supports multiple table that resolves to a single SQL query. Since it seems your business case can't be dealt with a single query you would have to look elsewhere like Populating report with data through code: http://www.riptutorial.com/acumatica/example/25273/this-article-covers-example-showing-how-to-create-report-using-memory-records-

Comment: In code you can issue the sub-query in the DataView delegate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the trick to achieve what I need.

To do this in Report Designer, the best would be to do a variable in the Detail section. It could be an `IIf` formula that returns TRUE if the `InventoryID` on the row is equal to the `InventoryID` that you are looking for or FALSE if not. Then you'd need to set the `ResetExpr` on the variable to reset to 0 when it reaches the next Order. Then you would need to move the fields from `groupHeaderSection2` to `groupFooterSection2` because the variable won't exist until after the Details section. Finally, you'd need to put the variable in the `VisibleExpr` field of `groupFooterSection2` so the section does not print when the variable is false. You will have to adjust the group totals accordingly by declaring the variables in `groupFooterSection2`.